# How do I use cleveref within section titles whose formatting is in uppercase?

Tags: cross-referencing, titles, cleveref, sectsty, uppercase

In my text, section titles should be in capital letters, so I used the `sectsty` package for this. However, when I want to put a `cleveref` inside the section title (which is in uppercase), the output is question marks. Note that when the title is not capitalized, `cleveref` appears correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\MakeUppercase}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}\label{chp:1}
\section{\Cref{chp:1}}% <------------- Produces ??
\subsection{\Cref{chp:1}}%  <--------- Appears correctly
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem there is that the first reference "sees" label `CHP:1`, which does not exist.

Comment: Joseph Wright has a nice article about it at TUGboat: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb41-1/tb127wright-case.pdf